# How to debug error on installation from APK?

Tags: installation

I'm working in a project. We are in a testing cycle and we are experiencing something that I don't know how to debug.

I built the APK. I installed it in my phone (S9+) and in many others with no problem. Then we sent the APK to some people to test it. 4 new Samsung S9. Totally new. No previous versions installed and same SDK and ONEUI and security patch as my own device.

When they try installing it they get an error on installation. I don't know what can be causing this and I don't know how to capture the error. How can I generate some log or debug it?

Comment: See [my list of logging apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_logcat). One of the bug reporters might be helpful. Apart from that: development questions are off-topic here – so we won't answer with the part of how to include such code with your app directly.

Comment: Samsung offers a [cloud device farm](https://program.developer.samsung.com/cloud-device-farm-lp/) that allows to remotely operate real test devices. May be you can reproduce the problem on one of those devices.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for the answers. The problem was cause by Google Protect. I just disabled it and now works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. The problem was cause by Google Protect. I just disabled it and now works perfectly. Thanks!